# Detach Wordpress Media Files In Bulk

Tags: custom-post-types, media, media-library

Just switched WP themes and I have about 1300 media files attached to what Wordpress is calling a 'Private Post'.

These Private Posts are actually photo portfolios from the previous theme. 200 portfolios, with 5-7 media files attached to each.

I need to detach this media before it can be used in the new theme. Right now its a manual, tedious process :(

I am hoping there is something I can change in the DB to detach these media files in one go.
Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what makes the post "attached" to another post is the `post_parent` field, the same mechanism used for child/parent pages. The Media in the media library is actually a post of type `attachment`. Note that you shouldn't need to detach them to be able to use another theme, and you can use the same attachment in multiple places even if it's already set to be "attached" to a single post

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply Tom, I appreciate it.

Here is a screenshot of my current situation:
https://share.getcloudapp.com/rRuzxG0X

These are images attached to a portfolio meta type contained in the previous theme. I dont see any way to attach them to another post without detaching from existing 'ghost/private post' first.

Comment: you don't need to attach them to be able to use them, what's the problem in the new theme you're trying to solve that requires you to re-attach them? Note that any custom post types the previous theme registered are still present in the database even if the new theme doesn't register them, they aren't lost forever

Comment: I am using a gallery plugin that uses a shortcode for each portfolio item, that attaches the media as a gallery to that specific portfolio (where the media is attached).

Comment: would I be right to guess that you're doing this so you can create new pages with that shortcode and attach the images to them so you can get your portfolios on the new theme?

Comment: That is correct. I create the portfolio, add the shortcode inside the text editor, then attach the media to the portfolio. When the portfolio is opened, the gallery appears.

Comment: you could also register a custom post type with the same name as the one your old theme registered and all your old portfolio posts would be there. They're still in the database, WordPress is just unaware of them. Take a look at the `register_post_type` function, your old theme will use it somewhere and the first parameter is what you need to copy. Then you can either register it in a plugin or child theme, or use a plugin to create the post type with a GUI. No detaching media, no creating new pages

Comment: Thanks for all of this info. Definitely given me a place to start. Have a great day.

Comment: Making progress after adding registering the OG theme's post type. The ghosts now have a home: https://share.getcloudapp.com/lluXpoZD

Comment: Mission accomplished. I am grateful for you assistance Tom. Hopefully I can assist someone here with the same efficacy in which you have helped me. Take care.

Comment: ah just needs writing up! Can't mark a comment as the solution

Answer (score 1):

You should register the post type from the old theme, all the posts are still there in the database WordPress just doesn't know to look for them.

Use the `register_post_type` with the same slug/post type name, and your old portfolio posts will reappear, no need to detach and re-attach to new pages